# How can I use the useSelector in a class commponent?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How can I use this useSelector in a class component?

```
const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});
```

Comment: React hooks are not compatible with class-based components. Why not just use the `connect` Higher Order Component from `react-redux`? Is that your selector function?

Comment: yes this is my selector, i just wanted to know if it was possible

Comment: No, the `useSelector` hook isn't compatible. You can use the selector function in `mapStateToProps` function though.

Comment: oh okay. Thank you

Comment: `useSelector` (note that the name starts with "use") is a React Hook. As per rules of react hooks, you can not use a React Hook in a class component. But you can convert your class component to a function component if you like hooks. Check https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html and https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector